# Lp spaces and supremum

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $p,q>0$ such that $1/p+1/q=1$ and $f,g>0$.
We work in $L^p$ spaces.

Prove that $\sup_{||f||_p=1} \int fg=||g||_q$

I proved that $\sup_{||f||_p=1} \int fg \leqslant ||g||_q$ but i find difficulties to  come up with a function $f$ such that $||f||_p=1$ for which the equality holds.

Can someone give me a little help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Extremal_equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must write $p,q \geq 1.$ To answer your question:

Think about when, equality holds in holder inequality. +  You always can scale function to get $||f||_p=1$.